# Reason for kernel panic? Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address ebfeb0a0

Tags: linux, memory, cpu, scheduled-tasks, kernel

This is regarding imx6q, 2GB Alliance Memory (4Gb x 4, 4 RAM chips) custom hardware design which is most similar to nitrogen6_max. This hardware was stable and could run Yocto without any failures.

**But now it is unstable and get kernel panics randomly. Here I have attached kernel log. Is this a memory problem ? When I do the program counter decoding using addr2line it shows >>Prepare_to wait_event, netlink_compare_arg_init << in different occasions. Any idea of this ?**

**Kernel Log**

```
Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address ebfeb0a0
pgd = b3fd4fff
[ebfeb0a0] *pgd=187e2722(bad)
Internal error: Oops: 80000005 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM
Modules linked in: brcmfmac brcmutil cfg80211 usb_f_ecm g_ether usb_f_rndis libcomposite u_ether videobuf2_dma_sg ov5642_camera ov5640_camera_mipi_int mxc_v4l2_capture ipu_bg_overlay_sdc atmel_mxt_ts ipu_still ipu_prp_enc ipu_csi_enc tc358743_h2c_bridge ov5640_subdev_camera goodix ipu_fg_overlay_sdc tsc2004 ili210x ft5x06_ts egalax_ts v4l2_int_device tw6869 videobuf2_dma_contig videobuf2_memops gpio_keys galcore(O)
CPU: 1 PID: 104 Comm: cryptomgr_test Tainted: G           O    4.1.15-1.0.0_ga+yocto+g76c24a0 #8
Hardware name: Freescale i.MX6 Quad/DualLite (Device Tree)
task: ce564600 ti: fedf4000 task.ti: ce5be000
PC is at 0xebfeb0a0
LR is at printk+0x90/0xac
pc : [<ebfeb0a0>]    lr : [<8085a290>]    psr: 20030193
sp : fedf6170  ip : fedf6170  fp : fedf6194
r10: 00000001  r9 : fedf62c0  r8 : ebfeb0a0
r7 : a9277bff  r6 : 80a8c8f8  r5 : 80d02508  r4 : ebfeb0a0
r3 : fedf6000  r2 : 5aede52e  r1 : fedf619c  r0 : 80a8c8f8
Flags: nzCv  IRQs off  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
Control: 10c5387d  Table: 5e7cc04a  DAC: 00000015
Process cryptomgr_test (pid: 104, stack limit = 0xce5be210)
Stack: (0xfedf6170 to 0xce5c0000)
Backtrace: invalid frame pointer 0xfedf6194
Code: bad PC value
---[ end trace 2854d5881dd1d8c6 ]---
Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed!
INFO: rcu_preempt detected stalls on CPUs/tasks:
        3: (6 GPs behind) idle=c63/140000000000000/0 softirq=12514/12514 fqs=1387
        (detected by 1, t=2102 jiffies, g=9717, c=9716, q=38)
Task dump for CPU 3:
swapper/3       R running      0     0      1 0x00000002
Backtrace:
[<8085c670>] (__schedule) from [<8085cbc4>] (schedule+0x44/0x9c)
 r9:ce0a9fa8 r8:00000001 r7:d0f23ed0 r6:809028c0 r5:80d025e8 r4:ce0a8000
[<8085cb80>] (schedule) from [<8085cfa8>] (schedule_preempt_disabled+0x18/0x24)
 r5:80d025e8 r4:ce0a8000
[<8085cf90>] (schedule_preempt_disabled) from [<801681ac>] (cpu_startup_entry+0x134/0x330)
[<80168078>] (cpu_startup_entry) from [<8010e348>] (secondary_start_kernel+0x150/0x15c)
 r7:80d51308
[<8010e1f8>] (secondary_start_kernel) from [<1010154c>] (0x1010154c)
 r5:00000015 r4:5e08806a
Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address ebfeb0a0
pgd = b3fd4fff
[ebfeb0a0] *pgd=187e2722(bad)
Internal error: Oops: 80000005 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM
Modules linked in: brcmfmac brcmutil cfg80211 usb_f_ecm g_ether usb_f_rndis libcomposite u_ether videobuf2_dma_sg ov5642_camera ov5640_camera_mipi_int mxc_v4l2_capture ipu_bg_overlay_sdc atmel_mxt_ts ipu_still ipu_prp_enc ipu_csi_enc tc358743_h2c_bridge ov5640_subdev_camera goodix ipu_fg_overlay_sdc tsc2004 ili210x ft5x06_ts egalax_ts v4l2_int_device tw6869 videobuf2_dma_contig videobuf2_memops gpio_keys galcore(O)
CPU: 1 PID: 104 Comm: cryptomgr_test Tainted: G           O    4.1.15-1.0.0_ga+yocto+g76c24a0 #8
Hardware name: Freescale i.MX6 Quad/DualLite (Device Tree)
task: ce564600 ti: fedf4000 task.ti: ce5be000
PC is at 0xebfeb0a0
LR is at printk+0x90/0xac
pc : [<ebfeb0a0>]    lr : [<8085a290>]    psr: 20030193
sp : fedf6170  ip : fedf6170  fp : fedf6194
r10: 00000001  r9 : fedf62c0  r8 : ebfeb0a0
r7 : a9277bff  r6 : 80a8c8f8  r5 : 80d02508  r4 : ebfeb0a0
r3 : fedf6000  r2 : 5aede52e  r1 : fedf619c  r0 : 80a8c8f8
Flags: nzCv  IRQs off  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
Control: 10c5387d  Table: 5e7cc04a  DAC: 00000015
Process cryptomgr_test (pid: 104, stack limit = 0xce5be210)
Stack: (0xfedf6170 to 0xce5c0000)
Backtrace: invalid frame pointer 0xfedf6194
Code: bad PC value
---[ end trace 2854d5881dd1d8c6 ]---
Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed!
INFO: rcu_preempt detected stalls on CPUs/tasks:
        3: (6 GPs behind) idle=c63/140000000000000/0 softirq=12514/12514 fqs=1387
        (detected by 1, t=2102 jiffies, g=9717, c=9716, q=38)
Task dump for CPU 3:
swapper/3       R running      0     0      1 0x00000002
Backtrace:
[<8085c670>] (__schedule) from [<8085cbc4>] (schedule+0x44/0x9c)
 r9:ce0a9fa8 r8:00000001 r7:d0f23ed0 r6:809028c0 r5:80d025e8 r4:ce0a8000
[<8085cb80>] (schedule) from [<8085cfa8>] (schedule_preempt_disabled+0x18/0x24)
 r5:80d025e8 r4:ce0a8000
[<8085cf90>] (schedule_preempt_disabled) from [<801681ac>] (cpu_startup_entry+0x134/0x330)
[<80168078>] (cpu_startup_entry) from [<8010e348>] (secondary_start_kernel+0x150/0x15c)
 r7:80d51308
[<8010e1f8>] (secondary_start_kernel) from [<1010154c>] (0x1010154c)
```

r5:00000015 r4:5e08806a

Regards,
Kulunu.

Comment: A suggestion for you on another site was to also post the hardware and software stack. What system, software and what were you attempting at the time?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the kernel, possibly because it can't handle your hardware. What did you change? Some new driver? Can you go back to the state where it was stable?

Comment: Hi Kulunu, as @SolarMike explains, this isn't any clearer than the identical question [you've asked on EE.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/318374/unable-to-handle-kernel-paging-request-at-virtual-address-ebfeb0a0-reason-for-k?noredirect=1). Please do take the time, investigate what could be wrong, write a better description and amend your question. For the time being, I think this should be closed as unclear.